# IOS efficient wake word method

Tags: ios, swift, siri, voice-control

I used the speech recognition framework to implement wake word in my app, but it turns out that it's a high battery impact solution, because it is always listening to the mic input.

I tried looking for some external providers for this task like PicoVoice and Hondify but they are not cost-efficient for me.

I also saw that in the new ios 13 there is a voice control feature but I'm not sure there is a way to inject a new command from within the app.

Is there a battery efficient solution (low battery impact) to implement wake word inside the app?

Thank you.